# How to Change SAPI VOICES in Windows [PHP]

Tags: text, speech

I have basic code which works as:

```
$voice = new COM("SAPI.SpVoice");
voice .Speak("hello world");
```

I am getting RID of default voice, So
I am now looking at a way to change which voice is getting used for the TTS.
I want to change SAPI voice to ZIRA

What is the correct way to change the default voice, I read some thread here , But it is in javascript, and it is not working.

my code :

```
@$submit = $_POST['process'];
@$word = $_POST['texttospeech'];

$voice = new COM("SAPI.SpVoice");




if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and isset($submit) and !empty($word)){
    $voice->Speak($word);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <title>PHP Text to Speech</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/fav.png" type="image/png">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body onload="startTime()">
        <nav class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/cod.png" class="hederimg">
            </a>
            <div id="clockdate">
                <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
                    <div id="clock"></div>
                    <div id="date"><?php echo date('l, F j, Y'); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="topmost">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <center>
                            <strong class="panelinputtitle">PHP Text to Speech Converter Using Microsoft Speech API</strong>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method = "POST">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="6" name="texttospeech" placeholder="Type your Text Here..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary btn-block" name="process" value="Speak">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>




    </body>




</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched this one a long time ..
At least selecting Zira within the control panel as default voice works

[image: Zira]